# Exstimation of a Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

this is an exercise I found online searching for Lebesgue measure exercises. I'm really at a loss as to how to proceed to find its solution.

Exercise: Let Q be the unit cube in $\mathbf {R}^n $. Find a function 
$\phi$ ∈ $C_c(Q, [0, 1])$ (all the functions $f: Q \rightarrow  [0,1]$, f function of compact support) such that

$$\int_{R^n} |\chi_Q − \phi| \, dx < {1\over 10}
$$

There are two more points, but it's no use writing them here, as I cannot even solve the first one. I wanted to write some of the ideas I had, but instead I really don't know where to start from. Obviously I know the cube is measurable, compact. I thought of some property like the Tchebishev one, but that's really about something else. The exercise is asking for an extimation of that integral over the whole $\mathbf {R}^n $ and I've never done anything of the like. Would someone be willing to just point out to me which properties or theorems I should be thinking of?

Comment: Can you do it for the case of $n=1$?

Comment: In case of n=1 we squeeze the cube to a point, so I would be evaluating the integral over the real axis of the distance between this point and its traslation, right?

Comment: What do you mean by squeeze the cube to a point? The cube is fixed (it's the unit cube in $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: (I'm reading more about the Urysohn's lemma, never heard of it, I'll reply later to you if I can get what you mean!)

Comment: In the case $n=1$, what you need is to find a function $\phi$, continuous and with compact support, which approximates the "window function" $$\chi_Q(x)=\begin{cases}
1, &\mbox{if $x\in\left[0,1\right]$} \\
0, &\mbox{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$ in the $L^1$ sense.

Comment: What I mean is a cube in $ \mathbb R^n $ degenerates to a point in $ \mathbb R $. I thought this is what Andres Majia meant. Oh I see, stupid me, it becomes a segment of lenght 1

Comment: OP is thinking of characteristic function as constant on the cube, so "squeezing it to a point." I think this is the wrong intuition. One should think of it in the $n=1$ case as a function $f:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$.

Comment: Urysohn's lemma is actually just an idea.  You don't need to apply it, and it actually won't be much good to you, because it's an existence theorem, and you need to reach a numerical bound. It's the proof of the lemma might that might help you.

Comment: Not getting it right now, I've to think this through

Comment: Ok I've thought about the n=1 case. For example, if you consider the function

$$\chi_Q(x)=\begin{cases} -(x-1/2)^2+1, &\mbox{if $x\in\left[0,1\right]$} \\ 0  (or  a  costant < {1\over10}), &\mbox{otherwise} \\ \end{cases}$$

then you integrate it all over $\mathbb R$

Comment: then you integrate it all over $\mathbb R$ and you have an approximation inferior to  ${1\over10}$. But this is a very specific function, the first I thought about, I suppose I should try and find something less specific

Comment: You're in the right track, but I believe it's easier to do the opposite: make $\phi$ constant *inside* the cube (equal to $1$), and make it decrease quickly to zero as soon as it gets outside the cube.

Comment: So basically something like this $$ \phi=\begin{cases} 1, &\mbox{if $x\in\left[0,1\right]$} \\ {1\over(x-3)^2}, &\mbox{otherwise} \\ \end{cases} $$ this should do for the estimation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma). You could, for example, define another cube $Q'$ containing $Q$ properly, and then define:

$$A = Q$$
$$B = \mbox{complement of $Q'$ in $\mathbb R^n$}$$
$$\phi(x) = \frac{d(x,B)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$$

Here, $d(x,A)$ is the distance from $x$ to $A$.

Now, to get $\phi$ as close as possible to $\chi_Q$, you just have to get $Q'$ as close as possible to $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

With $Q=[0,1]^n,$ set

$$ \psi(x) = \sin(\pi x_1)\cdot \sin(\pi x_2) \cdots \sin(\pi x_n)$$

for $x\in Q.$ Extend $\psi$ to $\mathbb R^n$ by setting it equal to $0$ everywhere else. For $m=1,2,\dots, $ define $\phi_m = \psi^{1/m}.$ Each $\phi_m \in C_c(Q),$ and

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \int_Q|1-\phi_m| = 0.$$